# Search for a pattern in a lot of scramble letters (upper & lower cases)

Tags: python

I have a lot of scrambled letters. In these letters i should find a pattern of `XXXxXXX`.

Which means, three uppercase letters then one lowercase then another three uppercase.

I am using Python to solve this problem, is there a way to do that easily?

Also, I would like to print just the lowercase letters without the uppercase ones. How can I do that?

Comment: look at the python regex library. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Do all of the letters have to be the same?  Or, should 'ABCdEFG' match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
>>> a='alRfflkafdfaeGlkAYEuRFSbbvvcbF'
>>> import re
>>> r=re.compile("[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}")
>>> r.findall(a)
['AYEuRFS']
```

Comment: it is working, but needs some tweaking, i need that just the three uppercase letters pattern would be the results, with what you have it give me even a pattern like this:
ERWSgWRW
which isn't good for me. i need a pattern with **just** 3 upper.

Comment: i have found the solution for me, i have just added [a-z] in from of the first [A-Z] and in back of the last [A-Z].